# How to retrieve radiobutton from radiogroup using kotlin android extentions

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I'm programmatically adding and removing radiobuttons from a radiogroup in my fragment. The onCheckedChangeListener provides a reference to the radiogroup and the integer id of the checked radiobutton. I can get a reference to the radiobutton by using findViewById, but can I do this using kotlin android extentions?

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        radio_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener({ radioGroup: RadioGroup, i: Int ->

            // This may give index out of bounds exception
            someFunction((radioGroup[i-1] as RadioButton).text as String)

            // This works but I don't want to use findViewById
            val rb: RadioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(i) as RadioButton
            onRadioButtonSelect(rb.text as String)            
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extensions are compile-time. However, you are looking to find the id at runtime. So You'll not be able to use kotlin extensions with dynamically added radio buttons